# Why selenium webdriver doesnt write an automated message on LinkedIn message box

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, webdriver

I need help with this code, please.

What I'm trying to do is follow a tutorial on Youtube, the aim is to automatically write a random message, let's say the phrase 'testing' into the first contact (1st level connections) of my LinkedIn profile from the first page of my search page.
All good so far the first part of the code, I am able to open the website, log in and search the fist level contacts...

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
import time

# Create an instance of the WebDriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()

# Navigate to the website
driver.get("https://www.linkedin.com")


# Wait for the login page to load
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

username = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@name='session_key']")))
password = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@name='session_password']")))
# Enter the login credentials
username.send_keys("email@gmail.com")
password.send_keys("password")
password.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.url_contains("linkedin.com/feed"))

# Navigate to the search results page for the first level connections
driver.get("https://www.linkedin.com/search/results/people/?network=%5B%22F%22%5D&origin=FACETED_SEARCH")

 
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.search-results-container")))

message_button = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@aria-label='Message ']")))

message_button.click()


# Add a delay to allow time for the login process
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.msg-overlay-bubble-header")))



 # Here is where my problem starts... Find the message input box and enter the text.
 
   
main_div = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@class="msg-form__msg-content-container"]')

main_div.click()


paragraphs = driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME,'p')

paragraphs[-5].send_keys("Ciao")
```

My problem is when I want to write actually the message, my program just open the writte a message box, but doesnt write anything, in the code above I have identified with  # Here is where my problem starts... Find the message input box and enter the text.

I think it has to be something on how defined the XPATH